# Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: Function autooad not found

Tags: php

I would know if there something speficic in php 7.3.3-1+0~20190307202245.32+stretch~1.gbp32ebb2
because I have this error when I try to install a software.

```
:autoload' not found (class 'Core\\OM\\CORE' not found)



Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught LogicException: Function 'Core\\OM\\CORE::autoload' not found (class 'Core\\OM\\CORE' not found) in /var/www/.........../application.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/........./application.php(21): spl_autoload_register('Core\\\\OM...')\n#1 /var/www/clients/........./install/index.php(12): require('/var/www/client...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/........../install/includes/application.php on line 21'
```

On my localhost under linux, I have not this problem and everything works fine.
php : PHP Version 7.3.2-3

Thank you

For example in install.php directory  :

```
 use Core\OM\CORE;
 use Core\OM\HTML;

// set the level of error reporting
      error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

      define('CORE_BASE_DIR', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../includes/') . '/Core/');

      require(CORE_BASE_DIR . 'OM/CORE.php');
      spl_autoload_register('Core\OM\CORE::autoload')
```

about CORE.PHP

```
public static function autoload($class)  {
  $prefix = 'Core\\';

  if (strncmp($prefix, $class, strlen($prefix)) !== 0) {
    return false;
  }

  if (strncmp($prefix . 'OM\Module\\', $class, strlen($prefix . 'OM\Module\\')) === 0) { // TODO remove and fix namespace
    $file = dirname(CORE_BASE_DIR) . '/' . str_replace(['Core\OM\\', '\\'], ['', '/'], $class) . '.php';
    $custom = dirname(CORE_BASE_DIR) . '/' . str_replace(['Core\OM\\', '\\'], ['Core\Custom\OM\\', '/'], $class) . '.php';
  } else {
    $file = dirname(CORE_BASE_DIR) . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    $custom = str_replace('Core/OM/', 'Core/Custom/OM/', $file);
  }

  if (is_file($custom)) {
    require($custom);
  } elseif (is_file($file)) {
    require($file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you sometimes use escaped \ and sometimes not?

Comment: @Dharman : Could you explain and the line ?

Comment: It's an uncaught exception. Catch it and inspect the exception object to see what the problem is.

Comment: @miken32  When this command is executed spl_autoload_register('Core\OM\CORE::autoload') ,  I have the http 500 appear and the error describe above in the log. My problem is : path file is ok after verification. CORE.php is not read.

Comment: Typically when looking for a parameter of type `callable` where the function is namespaced, we would do something like `spl_autoload_register(['\\Core\\OM\\CORE', 'autoload']);`

Comment: But again, why aren't you catching any exceptions?

Comment: are you in windows :) and you may not have these folders ..is it  /var/www/  ??

Comment: No linux: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: message is above. 
Why it works on 7.3.2 and no 7.3.3. What's the difference ?